# Does one "glue a cut together"?, or "stick the cut up"? or what?

Tags: word-choice

Suppose, in order to repair a tire I apply glue to both sides of the cut and close it. How do I describe this action? I have invented a dozen of variants, but Google says that they all are bad English.

Answer (score 6):

You may say that you repaired the tire gluing the two parts/sides together.

***[To Glue](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/glue)***:

> - ***Fasten or join with or as if with glue.***
>
>   - *‘A cylinder was created from this rectangle, 12 inches tall, by gluing the ends together’*.

More usage examples:

> - 'the wood is cut into pieces which are then glued together.'
> - ‘Meticulously gluing them together piece by piece, Kaufman builds up feathered layers and leaflike clusters of paint.’
> - ‘Make sure to use pipe cleaner before gluing your pipe fittings together.’
> - ‘Seals are being pressed into service as mobile marine laboratories, with scientists gluing instruments to their backs in an attempt to find out more about global warming.’

(ODO)

Comment: +1 for "to glue".  I would use it like "glue the edges of the cut together".

Comment: and note that all these examples show that the idiomatic use of "to glue" is to say that you are gluing the pieces/edges/ends/seals' backs(!) together, not gluing the cut

Answer (score -1):

Far more important than what verb you use is that, if we're talking about a cut in a tire, "cut" is not the idiomatic word to use. Almost 100% of the time you would say "hole". "Cut" has a fairly strong biological connotation - it refers to an opening in human tissue. For tires specifically, you can also say "puncture".

I would say that using the word "cut" could actually make it hard for English speakers to understand you. For example, when I read the title of this question, I thought you were talking using glue on an actual wound on a person.

The most natural expression for me would be:

> *Glue the hole shut*

Comment: Will the word "slit" do? It is important to me that the hole is infinitely this, like that made by scissors, or a very sharp knife. In cotrast to round holes a slit can be repaired by gluing the sides together

Comment: @Serguei Slit is fine.